# TypeScript - Make sure an array contains all keys of an object constant

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, enums

I have a const object (simulating enums). I want to take the keys of that object and put them in to an array. I want TypeScript to throw an error when one of them keys is missing from the array.

```
// My Enum.
export const Status = {
    'ACTIVE': 'Active',
    'DELETED': 'Deleted'
} as const;

// Enums keys and values.
export type StatusKeys = keyof typeof Status;
export type StatusValues = typeof Status[StatusKeys];

// I want TypeScript to recognise 'DELETED' is missing and throw an error.
// Ideally this will be done dynamically without the need to maintain another variable.
export const ArrayStatus: StatusKeys[] = ['ACTIVE'];
```

The idea behind it is that I will get errors any time I add or remove entries to that const object  so I can update my code.

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't just fill from `Status`, eg. -> `export const ArrayStatus: StatusKeys[] = Object.keys(Status) as StatusKeys[];`   Or even `export const ArrayStatus = Object.keys(Status) as StatusKeys[];` as doing the Type assertion will then implicitly  set `ArrayStatus` type.

Comment: @Keith That will return all the values of Status. I want to be able to exclude values in the array whilst still getting type completion on the values I haven't explicitly excluded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your after a union type, converted to array with typechecking.

Then this -> https://catchts.com/union-array  might be what your after.

eg.

```
// My Enum.
export const Status = {
    'ACTIVE': 'Active',
    'DELETED': 'Deleted'
} as const;

// Enums keys and values.
export type StatusKeys = keyof typeof Status;
export type StatusValues = typeof Status[StatusKeys];

// I want TypeScript to recognise 'DELETED' is missing and throw an error.
// Ideally this will be done dynamically without the need to maintain another variable.

type TupleUnion<U extends string, R extends any[] = []> = {
    [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? [...R, S] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S]>;
}[U];

export const ArrayStatus: TupleUnion<StatusKeys> = ['ACTIVE', 'DELETED'];

export const ArrayStatusNoDelete: TupleUnion<Exclude<StatusKeys, 'DELETED'>> = ['ACTIVE']
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFkE9QUQOwK4FsB0AoApgDwA4HsAnAF1AGM84BnEgZSIEMiFLQBeUAbzVB9AHIAggGEAKgEkAajD4AufgNJEAlgDcMfADTdefACIwAMjBExds-rowAbDEQwATPmgC%20oei3JUiAbjRoQsIhILADWGJAs9HD2oCr0VggYlOjY%20MSgRJA4GKB0jMwA0uEs7GGQeABmGVkYlbkMTJS%20qYQkmdn1%20ZQS8Ykl1dl1eY0A2sOFxQC6vv5gYqAA7lEkIjU0pARKOG14oAQY5ADmcEqUOXqGxqZ8oKegSKeUSnCHbtEZABYEeAtvoBgEb4EdABMT2DDxKzQIgfO4LJRWKygABGOXsFDRkDg9AepEh0HhMLwCDaHxycAwDgyuyQ9GeDGebzwMIBsXom3oyJs6DQ7RyIgQOBsAFUThQADzC-5YOzRFjUTYvDSgABK0tl9kicEgI0mbFAuoAfPquABIMa3OCgYWTOQwLCkBLgyXKmjG7AalgUtQEUAAfgNKCDKtderkAqFGFFSgl9sdCGdwtdhuVIyDKBDuUmht8zhGNpmLXSnmooAEgPokHGlHDgpFYrg4urRQixvYI0Eokk0mVFyMJjM0z8RZIJZI5YIlerADk8JYbHZa5Ho7GHU6ME2GhMIr39P3roa2wbO%20IpHxJkA)

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thanks very much Keith for your assistance.